# How to call on two variables in Excel to Cc outlook email?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

This macro uses an HTML file that holds the template to send mass emails.

I set up a function to call on a column of email addresses to fill the CC.

Needs have changed and I would like to not condense two columns into one to CC two people.

I tried making a second function to add the second variable to the CC.

I'd like .Cc = email@email.com; email@email.com

The macro pulls from pre-filled email address list which is why it has a range in the function.

```
Sub PreviewEmail(wsNew As Worksheet, looper As Range, month As Range, year As Range)

'Macro Purpose: To send an email through Outlook

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ToEmailList As String
    Dim CcEmailList As String
    Dim CcEmailListT As String
    Dim sSubject As String
    Dim sName As String
    Dim line As String
    Dim oFSO
    Dim oFs
    Dim pathName As String

    pathName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\template.htm"

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFs = oFSO.OpenTextFile(pathName)

    ToEmailList = setToEmail
    CcEmailList = setCcEmail
    CcEmailListT = setCcEmailT
    sSubject = "This is a test"
    sName = setSendName

    Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

    If OutApp Is Nothing Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set rng = wsNew.Range("A1:F" & wsNew.UsedRange.Rows.Count)

    With OutMail
        stext = oFs.readall
        For Each cell In looper
            line = line & cell.Text & " " & cell.Offset(0, 1).Text & " <br />"
        Next

        stext = Replace(stext, "%variable%", line)
        stext = Replace(stext, "monthmonthmonth", month.Text)
        stext = Replace(stext, "yearyearyear", year.Text)

        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "JPMC Workforce Screening"
        .To = ToEmailList
        .Cc = CcEmailList, CcEmailListT
        .Subject = sSubject
        .HTMLBody = stext
        .Display

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
.Cc = CcEmailList, CcEmailListT
```

with

```
.Cc = CcEmailList & ";" & CcEmailListT
```